# IntelliJ Idea shortcut not working

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ Idea IDE, and have assigned <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to build projects shortcut. Unfortunately it is not working. However, I do get it working if I first open the 'Build' menu, and then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>. I know <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> is assigned to save project, and I purposedly want to always build the project on save. Is it wrong or errorneus to assign one shortcut to two actions?

**How to get <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to work as a shortcut for building the project, simultaneously allowing it to be a shortcut for save?**

Comment: Building project triggers save automatically anyway. You can also record a macro to save all + build and then assign a shortcut to this macro.

Comment: Just go to Preferences, then "Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler", then check the checkbox "Build project automatically". No need to even save anything, and no need to reassign the universal "Save" keyboard shortcut to something other than "Save".

Comment: I don't want the project to be build automatically. Then it will build always when I type. I want it to build only when I save.